# Promise in promise?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

Is there any way I can make the following work:

**function A**

This function returns a promise that does a task which uses multiple *webworkers*, once the webworkers have collectively finished this task it will resolve the promise.

**function B**

This function executes function A, and after that it executes multiple other functions that require A to have been done first.

**function C**

This function executes function B, and after that it executes multiple other functions that require A. This function may onle be called *once*, as it is a single process which improves a certain genetic algorithm task by executing function B multiple times sequentially. (so no callback B -> C).

---

Something like this:

```
var someObject = {test: null};

function A () {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // do some task which requires webworkers
    someObject.test = 10;
  });
}

async function B(){
    await A();

  someObject.test *= 4;
  return someObject.test;
}

function C(){
    // set up complicated options here


  // a loop using these options
  var i = 100;
  while(i--){
    var x = B();

    console.log(x);
    // do tasks that require B;
  }
}

C();
```

View it [here on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yhfv6t4v/), please note that I want to avoid any kind of callbacks because I am already working with a complicated object architecture (i'm doing neuro-evolution).

The best thing I could think of is somehow wrapping function B in a promise as well, but I haven't figured out how to do that.

Comment: do you mean something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/yhfv6t4v/1/

Comment: @MaxSemikin please post that as an answer, you have no clue how dumb I feel for not knowing that I could call `await` on async functions (I thought it was just for promises).

Comment: would be grateful if you mark it as correct then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can as well call `await` on `async` functions as they implicitly return a promise:

```
var someObject = {test: null};

function A () {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // do some task which requires webworkers
    someObject.test = 10;
    setTimeout(resolve, 1000);
  });
}

async function B(){
  await A();

  someObject.test *= 4;
  return someObject.test;
}

async function C(){
  // set up complicated options here
  // a loop using these options
  var i = 100;
  while(i--){
    var x = await B();

    console.log(x);
    // do tasks that require B;
  }
}

C();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could return a promise from B(). Note, you don't need to resolve `someObject` in B() (i.e. `resolve(someObject.test)`) because it's a global var, but I did in order to demonstrate how to resolve a value and to follow your example code. Also note I removed the loop for example sake.

**EDIT** - thanks to [@t.niese](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1960455/t-niese) and others for pointing out the anti-pattern in my original answer. Please see the updated answer, below

https://jsfiddle.net/ey07zy6h/9/

```
var someObject = {test: null};

function A () {
    console.log('in a')
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // do some task which requires webworkers
        someObject.test = 10;
        resolve()
  });
}

function B() {
    console.log('in b')
    return A()
    .then(() => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        someObject.test *= 4;
        resolve(someObject.test);
    }))
    .catch(e => {
        console.log('Err in A: ' + e)
    })
}

function C() {
    // set up complicated options here
    console.log('in c')

    // a loop using these options
    var i = 100;
    // while(i--) {
    B()
    .then(data => {
        let x = data;
        console.log('X is: ' + JSON.stringify(x));
        // do tasks that require B;
    })
    .catch(e => {
        console.log('Err in B', e)
    })
  // }
}

C();
```

Comment: `A` already returns a promise so you should not wrap that in an `new Promise` callback. Just return the chain that was build on `A`.

Comment: But he needs to wait for A to finish before performing work in B. Work which itself could be asynchronous. Here he is using the dummy code: `someObject.test *= 4;` but this could be asynchronous in a real world example and thus require a promise, no?

Comment: `return A().then(...).catch(...)` will return a promise and have the same effect as your code. Writing `new Promise((resolve, reject) => { A().then ... })` is an antipattern if `A` already returns a Promise.

Comment: Imagine if the code `someObject.test *= 4;`, within function B, was replaced with an XMLHttpRequest. How would he wait for that to be finished in the function C? Can someone provide the code? I'm just not seeing it without a new promise.

Comment: You for sure would use a Promise that is either returned by the async function you call, or that is created by you **within** the `then` callback. `return A().then(() => new Promise ((resolve, reject) => ajaxRequest( ... resolve() ... reject() ...))`

Comment: the `.catch` in B would likely never be called due to an error in `A`, because `A` never rejects. So the message in that `.catch` is misleading. Also, if that catch fires, then B will **resolve** to the value `undefined` - (in fact, `B` can never return a rejected promise) - which means the `.then` code in `C` will run with a value `undefined`, and there's no way the `.catch` in `C` will run